# How to ignore an incoming argument to a declarative SQLAlchemy class?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a class:

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()


class DataFromWeb(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'data'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
```

Now I'm getting from the web a JSON array which also have several other fields (in which obviously I'm not interested in, and could change but shouldn't break the app).

This is the error: `TypeError: 'timestamp' is an invalid keyword argument for DataFromWeb`. But there could be more fields. I'm just not interested in them.

Is there a nice way to ignore them? Or tell SQLAlchemy that the `Column`s I've given are the only ones I'm interested in?

One way I found is this:

```py
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Gotta clean up the kwargs here :(
        kwargs2 = {k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if hasattr(self.__class__, k)}
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
```

But this is just ugly in my opinion...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [default constructor](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/da4e4cb1c67230abd67e487cfb1bda8cd6910029/lib/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py#L826) for declarative models essentially performs the same `hasattr` loop as that in the question, but raises a `TypeError` if a kwargs key doesn't map to the name of an instance attribute, so the ugliness is unavoidable.

However, it can be hidden.  `declarative_base` accepts a [constructor](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base.params.constructor) argument which will override the default constructor, so you could provide your own implementation which ignores unknown names.  This way, you don't have to implement an `__init__` method on all your models to filter unwanted keys.

```py
def _declarative_constructor(self, **kwargs):
    """Don't raise a TypeError for unknown attribute names."""
    cls_ = type(self)
    for k in kwargs:
        if not hasattr(cls_, k):
            continue
        setattr(self, k, kwargs[k])


Base = declarative_base(constructor=_declarative_constructor)


class DataFromWeb(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'data'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # We don't really need an __init__ method, this is just 
        # for demonstration purposes.
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: That's a much nicer (and portable) solution! Thanks for the assist :)